# Remove backslash in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, backslash

I have the following array:

```
[ 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'67c8ca21-bcdf-4298-
aaf0-ae23c18510f1\')/$value',
'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'313fbef3-f53c-456f-
be75-1002a3b3e2a5\')/$value',
'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'31df567e-399b-4065-
9399-75f4233cba5f\')/$value',
'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'f643e5f4-3791-436e-
 b304-4d451391af4d\')/$value',
'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'9faebdb4-5697-4070-
 aafe-2c2d1ee99a06\')/$value' ]
```

The array is the result of this expression:

```
 requestarray = [];
for (i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
    requestarray.push(url_search + "(" + "'" + data[i] + "'" + ")/$value");
}
```

Why are the "\" inserted and how could I avoid or fix it?

Comment: You can use JSON.parse(array) for fix that.

Comment: if you want to put single quote inside single quote or double quote inside double quote, you need to escape it. e.g. `'\''` or `"\""`.

Comment: `['...'...']` would be invalid code. It *requires* a backslash. Whatever you're using to look at this array, it's trying to give you a valid code representation.

Comment: The backslash is not really there.  It just looks like it's inside the single quotes because the single quotes are backslash escaped.  e.g.: `\'phil\'`  I suppose it looks like there's a backslash after the last letter of `phil` inside a single quoted string.  But really it's just that the single quote that follows is escaped -- as is the initial single quote that sets off the UUID portion of that text.

Comment: Hi, does this mean, if i send the urls in a request, the '\' would not be recognized?

Comment: It won't be "not recognised", it's *not there*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My console happens to prefer to show me strings in double quotes:

[image: console demo]

I enter `"'"`, it responds with the same value.

I enter `'"'`, it responds with `"\""`. Both represent a string with length of `1` containing one double quote; but the one the console shows me is escaped with a backslash. That's because the console gives valid literal representations, and if the string is quoted with double quotes, any double quotes within it must be escaped.

**But this is purely presentational, the string does not actually contain the backslash.**

Answer (score -2):

The 'why' is because your strings contain single quotes, therefore the quotes within the final string are *escaped* by a \.

In your case you could avoid it because you put in the single quotes yourself, you might put in double quotes.

Comment: The backslashes aren't really there. You can iterate the string character by character and not find a backslash in it. Therefore it also can't be avoided. It's just for presentation.